# Method interception or validation of request params in Sitebricks controller

Tags: java, guice, sitebricks

I'm using Sitebricks with Guice to implement REST service and I have a set of methods like this:

```
@Get
@At("/:version/har/mostRecentEntry/assertResponseTimeWithin")
public Reply<?> doSomething(@Named("version") int version, Request<String> request) {
// Validation logic for request parameters ...

// Extracting parameters (converting url params to domain area objects)

// Actual business logic
}
```

Which leads to a lot of copy/pasted code.

I'm looking for some way to separate common validating & extracting data logic from request parameters. Probably I can use AOP to do it, but maybe there's easier way Sitebricks provides?

Answer (score 5):

A few considerations:

- Google's Sitebricks project is dead
- official site is down (sitebricks.org)
- last Github commit - 2015

My recommendation is to ***not*** build anything with that framework.

You should definitely consider alternatives for implementing REST services (e.g. [SpringBoot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)).

> maybe there's easier way Sitebricks provides?

That being said, Sitebricks doesn't seem to offer validation out of the box.

The code you can find related to validation in Sitebrick is:

```
@ImplementedBy(AlwaysValidationValidator.class)
public interface SitebricksValidator {

    Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>> validate(Object object);

}
```

and this:

```
public class AlwaysValidationValidator implements SitebricksValidator {

    @Override
    public Set<? extends ConstraintViolation<?>> validate(Object object) {
        return null; //unfinished
    }

}
```

This is unfinished implementation!

Your best option is to use [javax validation in a standalone setup](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/).
This includes [`hibernate-validator`](https://hibernate.org/validator/) + `javax expression language` - reference implementation of [`JSR 380`](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=380). It has a lot of build in [constraints](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-xml-configuration) (e.g. @NotNull, @Size etc.) and is [extensible](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints) - you can create your own constraints implementing the right interfaces (the AOP part is handled by the framework).

A more simple alternative is Guava's [PreConditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained).

Comment: Thank you, the considerations make perfect sense, if only I had chance to get rid of sitebricks.

Comment: You're welcome, but if you have to stick to Sitebricks, you can see the validation implementation is unfinished. You need to opt in using some framework (e.g. as I have suggested javax.validation - JSR 380), which does leverage AOP or do you your own implementation using something else.